# Destroy a particular session

Tags: php, symfony

I read about a way to [destroy a particular session using its ID in pure PHP](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.session-destroy.php#114709) and I would like to do the same using the Symfony services and components.
This must be done outside a controller (e.g. a console command).

However, I cannot find any service/component that handles the `session_commit` method.

Should I use it or is there any service/component I missed?

Comment: Since session_destroy does not take an ID, it destroys the current session, surely it would destroy the session that Symfony has established.  Session_commit is not necessary if you are destroying the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hereafter a way to kill a session using its ID (*Sorry I have no time to test that code but it should work fine*).

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session_id_to_kill = 'xxxxxxxx';

$session = new Session();
$session->setId($session_id_to_kill);
$session->start();
$session->invalidate();
```

If you have an active session (you perform this action through a controller action), you have to stop it before and restore it after you kill the other one.

```
$request->getSession()->stop(); // Stop the current session

// Kill the session using the same code as above

// Restart you session
$request->getSession()->start();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code looks good. I will try to use it next during week.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#session-data-management

From within your controller, you will have your request object. FOR GENERAL PURPOSE, you can use

```
$request->getSession()->clear();
```

or

```
$request->getSession()->remove("sessionKey");
```

for more info, you can read http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

```
example: getStorageKey()
```

Returns the key which the bag will ultimately store its array under in $_SESSION. Generally this value can be left at its default and is for internal use.

its all in the doc mention above

Comment: This is not what I need. Your code remove a particular key from the current session. I need to remove a **particular session** (i.e. not the current one).

Comment: `$request->getSession()` === the current session. This is not what I am looking for.